# Core Plot CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic Days only

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic on my x-axis which for time-line for days of a year (e.g. 07 March 2015).

This is my reference date:

```
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.month = 10
components.day = 29
components.year = 1970
components.hour = 0
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0
referenceDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)!
```

and here is part of my x axis style

```
x.labelingPolicy = .Automatic
let oneDay:NSTimeInterval = 60 * 60 * 24
x.majorIntervalLength = oneDay
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle

let timeFormatter = CPTTimeFormatter(dateFormatter: formatter)
timeFormatter.referenceDate = referenceDate
x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter
```

The problem is eventhough, the x values are NSDate at 00:00:00 of the days they do not stick to the gridline for that specific date:
[image]

but if I use .FixedInterval policy I get the correct behaviour but I loose the autmatic labeling on pinching.

[image]

How can I benefit from the two world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic labeling algorithm doesn't know about dates, so it won't split the axis into "nice" date intervals like days or weeks. Right now, the fixed interval labeling policy is the best solution. It is up to you to determine the proper interval based on the range being displayed. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/7) to add proper date support, but it's pretty low priority and I can't guarantee when it will be done.